# Comment associative array in PHP Documentor

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, phpdoc

I use several associative arrays in my PHP application and I'm using PHP documentor to comment my sources. I never really did specify comments for the arrays in an array, but now I need to do that and don't know how.

```
$array = array('id' => 'test', 'class' => 'tester', 'options' => array('option1' => 1, 'option2' => 2))
```

How do I comment this array in the correct way for `@var` and `@param` comments?
I could do this like this, but I don't know if this is correct:

```
@param string $array['id']
@param string $array['class']
@param int $array['options']['option1']
```

But how to do this for the `@var` part?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me this works fine in PhpStorm for nice return value description:

```
/**
 * @param string $requestUri
 * @return array[
 *  'controller' => string,
 *  'action' => string
 * ]
 */
```

Comment: Tried this in Webstorm 2020.1 EAP for a param description and it mangled the help popup. In my experience this doesn't work.

Comment: I can confirm this does not work with VSCode or PHPDocumentor either.

Comment: I voted your answer up, but I never accepted it. For me this was exactly what I was looking for back then. Thank you! I accepted it now. :D

Answer (score 32):

You can't document each key, but [you can tell phpDocumentor what type it is](http://www.icosaedro.it/phplint/phpdoc.html#literalarrays).

You could do something like this:

```
/**
 * Form the array like this:
 * <code>
 * $array = array(
 *   'id'      => 'foo',          // the id
 *   'class'   => 'myClass',     // the class
 * );
 * 
 * </code>
 *
 * @var array[string]string 
 */
$array;
```

Comment: Has this been confirmed to work with auto-complete/intellisense in any IDEs, I wonder?  According to [the phpDoc ABNF for type definitions](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/for-users/types.html#abnf), there's no allowance for a type to be specified for the array index.  And it specifies array as `@var string[]` (the `array` component is only supposed to be present for "unspecified" arrays).

Comment: @Sepster I don't think most IDEs are smart enough to recognize this, unfortunately. Your mileage may vary, but I even find Zend Studio's implementation a bit lacking when it comes to this sort of accute type awareness.

Comment: Updated link for ABNF mentioned in Sepster's comment: https://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/types.html

Comment: The example is confusing, it's not possible by looking at the `@var` annotation which type is used for the array key or value. Now I can't figure out if the `string` type hint inside or after the squared brackets is specifying the type of the key.

Comment: The latest ABNF for types: https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md#appendix-a-types

Comment: I think this answer may be misleading. It says "phpDocumentor". However the link actually leads to "PHPLint". I think it's a different software. There's no reason why PHPLint syntax would also be valid phpDoc syntax.

Comment: While this does not answer the question directly, the provided solution is probably the best one. Better only to refactor the array into DTO.

Comment: As @Gherman pointed out the answer is misleading. 
The phpDocumentor documentation does not provide key hinting: https://docs.phpdoc.org/3.0/guide/references/phpdoc/types.html#arrays

Answer (score 12):

What works in Phpstorm is:

```
/**
 * @return array{ hand: Hand, card: CardType | null }
 */
```

Comment: This works perfectly for me. But where did you find this info?

Answer (score 11):

I would look at the [WordPress Inline Documentation Reference](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/best-practices/inline-documentation-standards/php/#1-1-parameters-that-are-arrays) for some hints, though it's not currently comprehensive.

Use @param or @var or @property, whichever is appropriate in your context

According to those guidelines, you might document your associative array like this:

```
/**
 * @property array $my_array {
 *     An array of parameters that customize the way the parser works.
 *
 *     @type boolean $ignore_whitespace Whether to gobble up whitespace. Default true.
 *     @type string $error_level What the error reporting level is. Default 'none'.
 *                               Accepts 'none', 'low', 'high'.
 * }
 */
```

Comment: This notation for documenting array structures has never made it into official PHPDoc spec despite serious discussion in 2013-14 about adding it.

Comment: Seems to be some related discussion at https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/issues/650

Comment: The WordPress guide seems similar to what Psalm recommends: https://psalm.dev/docs/annotating_code/type_syntax/array_types/#object-like-arrays