# Type declaration/hint/annotation for multiple return values

Tags: php, phpstorm

You can use "multiple return values" in PHP by returning an array which contains your return values. I'm aware that this is more or less a hack, but a well-established and widely used one.

Question: when using something like this, is there a possibility to hint/document the individual return values, either in the code itself or in the doc comment (specifically in PhpStorm)? From what I have found out so far, it's not possible in the code itself, there you can only use `array`? Not sure about doc comments...

---

I don't think that this is a duplicate of [PHPStorm Type hinting array of different types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29165580/phpstorm-type-hinting-array-of-different-types) - first, that question doesn't refer to "multiple return values" (which is the established term for this AFAIK), so I was unable to find it before posting this question; second, the OP of that question specifically wanted to know only about type annotation in doc comments, not about type hinting.

Comment: You can typehint only `array`, yes. That's all.

Comment: [deep-assoc-completion plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9927-deep-assoc-completion) can help here -- will hint for array keys. May also support special syntax to describe individual elements (types) -- but double check that.

Comment: Re "not a duplicate": 1) Closing as duplicate is not a punishment, it doesn't matter that you were unable to find it before, it's closed as duplicate **to point you to existing solutions.** 2) You've established yourself that native type hints can only hint `array`, so that's a dead end.