# How to document an array of [type]?

Tags: php, arrays, types, documentation, phpdoc

Say I have a function like this:

```
function theFunction() {
    $arr = array();
    for ($i=0;$i<10;$i++) {
        $arr[] = new theObject($i);
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

I need to document the return type of the function. I could of course just use`array`, but that does not provide all the information that can be provided, and doesn't tell the developer much about the true nature of the function.

How do I document the type "array of [type]" in PHPDoc?

Comment: have you tried `@var ObjectType[]`?

Comment: @Robert no, but searching for that gave a result! :) http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/for-users/types.html#arrays

Comment: See https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/issues/650

Comment: For anyone visiting this question, there is a much better duplicate question here with a comprehensive set of (correct) answers [PHPDoc type hinting for array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778564/phpdoc-type-hinting-for-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the documentation of [phpDocumentor](https://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/types.html#arrays)

> The value represented by Type can be an array. The type MUST be defined following the format of one of the following options:
>
> 1. **unspecified**, no definition of the contents of the represented array is given. Example: `@return array`
> 2. **specified containing a single type**, the Type definition informs the reader of the type of each array element. Only one Type is then expected as element for a given array.
>
>    Example: `@return int[]`
>
>    Please note that mixed is also a single type and with this keyword it is possible to indicate that each array element contains any possible type.
> 3. **specified containing multiple types**, the Type definition informs the reader of the type of each array element. Each element can be of any of the given types. Example: `@return (int|string)[]`
>
>    **Note**
>      many IDEs probably do not support this notation yet.

Comment: For multiple types, PHPStorm also seems okay with `int[]|string[]` but I'm not sure that it should be recommended over `(int|string)[]`.

Comment: I don't think int[]|string[] means the same than (int|string)[]. The first represents an array of int elements or an array of string elements. The latter represents an array that can have elements of both types mixed.

Answer (score 8):

In PHPDoc you can do the following for type hinting array members:

```
@var array<\My\Folder\ClassName>
```

### UPDATE

You can also explicitly declare the key for associative arrays as follows:

```
@var array<string, \My\Folder\ClassName>
```

And according to [the answer posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56935189/1697459) you can even explicitly declare the keys in case you would like to do so like this:

```
/**
 * @return array[
 *  'controller' => string,
 *  'action' => string
 * ]
 */
```

**Note:** *This is tested and works perfectly well in PHP storm:*

[image]

Comment: How do you document the key of the array as well? Could this work: `@var array<string, int>` (array mapping strings to ints) or `@var array<int, Type>` (array mapping ints to Type)? Thank you.

Comment: The link you provided me are about JavaScript. Associative arrays in PHP don't have numbered keys, the key is a string... How would you document that? Thank you!

Comment: @tonix, so sorry for that, I somehow thought this was about Javascript, but I was apparently no longer awake while answering. I updated my answer...

Comment: OK! Thank you! This `array<KeyType, ValueType>` syntax is pretty similar to Java's generics.

Comment: This answer is completely wrong. Proof that people don't even check what they copy and paste from Stack Overflow.

Comment: @BadHorsie I always try to thoroughly test and confirm the working of the code in my answers. I added a screenshot from my PHP-storm that I made today. As you see the Intellij IDE understands the type declaration perfectly well, so not sure why you accuse me of copy pasting without checking...

Comment: @Wilt Sorry, should've been more specific. I am referring to the `@var array<string>` syntax that remains from your original answer. I believe PhpStorm can interpret it but [phpDocumentor doesn't use this type of syntax](https://docs.phpdoc.org/guide/references/phpdoc/types.html#arrays). The standard way to define an array of strings would be `@var string[]`. The copy/paste comment was directed at all the people who upvoted the original answer with JavaScript context as well, not yourself.

Answer (score -1):

In PHP 7.4+ you can use [type declarations](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php) to enforce the return type of a method.

While this is not meant for documentation, it does a better job of documenting than phpDocs did.

In your case, you can do:

```
function theFunction(): array {
    return [];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If I'm remembering right you supply the return type and a description, can you not put it in the description?

```
/**
 * blah
 * @return array array of types
 */
```

Comment: That's what I'm doing now, but it would be neater to use the standard way if it existed :)