# PHPDoc - Specify the type of array keys

Tags: php, arrays, phpdoc

How can I specify the type of the keys in the documentation of a PHP method that returns an array?

---

For example, I use this for an array of objects `@return MyClass[]`.

But I want to comment an array like `array( 'string' => array( MyClass ) )`, is this possible?

Comment: @RahilWazir, I'm using `@return MyClass[]` to get code completion in PHPStorm and it works perfectly... Why should I not do it? How could I get correct code completion just saying `@return array`? ***EDIT:*** Also, it is in the official PHPDoc site: http://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/guides/types.html#arrays

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414103/best-way-to-document-array-options-in-phpdoc I don't know about PHPStorm code completion. But you can comment array keys in the answer given but i don't think it should work for code completion

Comment: Are you using an object as an array key?  If not, what autocompletion are you looking for from the array key variable when it's not an object?  I must be missing something.

Comment: There is no settled syntax for documenting the datatype of an array key, so I'm not confident that any IDE has tried to implement a way to derive it.  There is a proposed effort to use a "Generics" syntax to formalize a way to document the key's datatype (https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md#collections), but I'm not aware that any IDE has tried to implement that either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comment associative array in PHP Documentor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713710/comment-associative-array-in-php-documentor)

Answer (score 26):

Years after the question, it is possible to document array keys and values using, for example, `@return array<integer, string>` for an array of string values indexed by integer keys.

I do not know to what extent this syntax is standard and well supported. Tools such as [PHPCS](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer) or [Psalm](https://psalm.dev) do support it.

Answer (score -16):

Why would you need to specify the datatype. You can just access the values in the array by using a foreach to loop trough the results.

For example:

```
$arr = array("name" => "MikO", "street" => "straatnaam", "number" => "2");


//Here is key the first key, in this case: name, street, number
//And value are the values of the keys, in this case: MikO, straatnaam, 2

foreach($arr as $key => $value)
{
echo $key." ".$value."<br/>";
}
```

You can also extract some specific data out of it by using this:

```
echo $arr['name'];
```

If you want to go into the object:

```
foreach($arr as $objname => $objcontent)
{
 foreach($objcontent as $objnodename => $objnodevalue)
{
echo $objnodename." = ".$objnodevalue;
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, but fortunately I already know how to loop through an array :) What I want is adding proper documentation for that kind of array in order to get code hinting in my IDE, which has nothing to do with your answer...

Comment: @MikO O sorry, you can just add comments to your code or isn't that good enough?

Comment: That's probably good enough for (some) humans, but not for PHPStorm, which is not able to understand just text comments and give me code completion...