# PHP comment in array?

Tags: php, arrays, comments

I'm trying to comment out the snippet between ~/**********/~ in the below code inside of a php function:

```
       $photobody[]="<tr><td colspan=\"".$cols."\">
        <table width=\"100%\" border=\"0\">
        <tr><td width=\"33%\">
        <div align=\"left\" class=\"caption\">".$prev."</div></td>
        <td width=\"33%\">                         
    ~/***** <div align=\"center\" class=\"caption\">Photos 
        <strong>".($photonum-(($rows*$cols)-1))."</strong> to 
        <strong>".$endnum."</strong> of 
        <strong>".count($photos)."</strong>
    <br />".$photopage."</div> ****/~ 
        </td><td width=\"33%\">
        <div align=\"right\" class=\"caption\">".$next."</div></td></tr></table></td></tr>";
```

Having some difficulty. Is there something that I need to escape to get that section to comment out? Little help. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713710/comment-associative-array-in-php-documentor here you can get some help

Answer (score 2):

The section you want to comment is of pure HTML type. Thus you need to put HTML comment as shown:-

```
$photobody[]="<tr><td colspan=\"".$cols."\">
    <table width=\"100%\" border=\"0\">
    <tr><td width=\"33%\">
    <div align=\"left\" class=\"caption\">".$prev."</div></td>
    <td width=\"33%\">                         
<!-- <div align=\"center\" class=\"caption\">Photos 
    <strong>".($photonum-(($rows*$cols)-1))."</strong> to 
    <strong>".$endnum."</strong> of 
    <strong>".count($photos)."</strong>
<br />".$photopage."</div> --> 
    </td><td width=\"33%\">
    <div align=\"right\" class=\"caption\">".$next."</div></td></tr></table></td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 1):

For commenting used `<!--    -->`

```
$photobody[]="<tr><td colspan=\"".$cols."\">
        <table width=\"100%\" border=\"0\">
        <tr><td width=\"33%\">
        <div align=\"left\" class=\"caption\">".$prev."</div></td>
        <td width=\"33%\">                         
  <!--<div align=\"center\" class=\"caption\">Photos 
        <strong>".($photonum-(($rows*$cols)-1))."</strong> to 
        <strong>".$endnum."</strong> of 
        <strong>".count($photos)."</strong>
    <br />".$photopage."</div> -->
        </td><td width=\"33%\">
        <div align=\"right\" class=\"caption\">".$next."</div></td></tr></table></td></tr
```

Answer (score 0):

You should close the previous string with an extra `"` in order for the text after `/*` to be  a comment:

```
    "<td width=\"33%\">"                         
    /***** <div align=\"center\" class=\"caption\">Photos 
    <strong>".($photonum-(($rows*$cols)-1))."</strong> to 
    <strong>".$endnum."</strong> of 
    <strong>".count($photos)."</strong>
<br />".$photopage."</div> ****/
    "</td><td width=\"33%\">"
```